# Why isn't ConcurrentModificationException being thrown here?

Tags: java, iterator, concurrentmodification, fail-fast

Look at this little piece of code:

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
al.add("AA");
al.add("AB");
al.add("AC");
Iterator it = al.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
String s = (String)it.next();
if(s.equals("AB")){
al.remove(1);
}
}
```

Since ArrayList has **fail-fast iterator**, and clearly, the given ArrayList isn't made of fixed size arrays (*which would render the `remove()` method unusable*), the above code should have thrown `ConcurrentModificationException` but yes, it does not.

Also, if I insert a print statement in the loop (as the first statement), it shows that the loop does not iterate the third time and that it exits gracefully.

I know it sounds too stupid but the only reason I could think of *falsely* is the fact that the removal of the element happens **after** the element has been traversed by the iterator. But that just cannot be the case as the `modificationCount` is still modified by removal and so it must throw the Exception.

Just doing

```
while(it.hasNext()){
it.next();
al.remove(1);
}
```

does throw ConcurrentModificationException though.

Any insights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because the `hasNext()` method does not check the `modCount`:

```
public boolean hasNext() {
    return cursor != size;
}
```

So, after calling `remove(1)`, the size of the list will be 2 just like the cursor, and `hasNext()` will return false. The `next()` method will never be called and `modCount` will never be checked.

If you add a fourth element to the list before iterating, you will get the exception similarly to your second example.

Comment: Loved the accurate, short and wholesome answer! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The check for concurrent modification happens only during an Iterator's `next()` call but not within its `hasNext()` call as explained in [Bubletan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45387056/why-isnt-concurrentmodificationexception-being-thrown-here/45387252#45387252).

The [java documentation for `ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) clearly specifies that,

> Fail-fast iterators throw ConcurrentModificationException on a
>   best-effort basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program
>   that depended on this exception for its correctness: the fail-fast
>   behavior of iterators should be used only to detect bugs.

So, it's a wrong programming practice to modify a collection while it is being iterated.

Comment: Is the best-effort basis this bad that a change in a very simple flow remains undetected in all the executions I have carried out? I had believed that there is some other kind of signal handling thread that takes care of listening to modifications. From what you are telling me, if I try to remove the last element while traversing using an iterator, there'll be never an exception thrown because of the absence of any more next() calls, isn't it?

Comment: Bubletan's answer clears it all. It really shouldn't be called a best effort basis :D Thank you!